# pageContext array not accessible on netlify build

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, netlify

I don’t know why I can read this pageContext array content only locally but not on build

I can access to the entire array but I can’t access to the single element inside id:

```
2:09:56 PM: error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
2:09:56 PM:   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

**indexTemplate.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Layout from "../../components/Layout"


const IndexPage = ({data, pageContext}) => {
  const sliderRef = useRef();
  const {slideshow} = pageContext;
    return (
      <Layout >
          {typeof slideshow} 
/*
output:

Array(3)
   0: {duration: 4}
   1: {duration: 3}
   2: {duration: 2}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
*/
         {typeof slideshow[0].duration}
/*
on NETLIFY build:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
*/

      </Layout>
    )
  }
export default IndexPage;
```

p.s. locally it works

Comment: "Locally works but not on build" and "locally works"? Means that it does or it does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I use Gatsby for this project and that file was in `/pages` directory.

```
src  
└───pages
│   │   index.md
│   │   index.js
```

pages directory work in **development mode** in **build mode** works only if page files are in `/template` or different folder:

```
src  
└───pages
│   │   index.md
└───templates
    │   index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
const IndexPage = ({data, pageContext}) => {
  const sliderRef = useRef();
  const { slideshow= [] } = pageContext;
    return (
      <Layout>
```

My guess it's that the code is accessing `pageContext` when it's fully not hydrated with `slideshow` data. Adding a default value (empty array, `[]`) can bypass it while the context is being filled with the proper data. I'd need more context to understand what's going on exactly.

---

It's unclear for me if it does, or it doesn't work locally. However, if it only works in `gatsby develop` it means that it doesn't work. You need to be sure that works under `gatsby build` too to ensure that "it works", otherwise, your code is only working under certain conditions but not in the whole scope of Gatsby.

Comment: Thank you for the question but the problem was more stupid than that. The problem was that I use Gatsby for this project and that file was in /pages directory.
`- src`

`- - pages`

`- - - myfile.js`

pages directory work in development mode in build mode works only if page file are in * */template** or different folder:
`- src`

`- - pages`

`- - - .md files`

`- - templates`

`- - - page.js fies`